# Using Firebase return an image that is linked to a user account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on an app using android studio and currently have a working login using Firebase user authentication. However, I am trying to have an image appear on the screen when the user logs after using this authentication. I want this image to be linked to that specific user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a photo url on a user's firebase profile with the following code:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

You would then retrieve the user's profile information (including their photo URL) like so:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    // Check if user's email is verified
    boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
```

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

If you're using oAuth authentication and want to retrieve their profile photo from facebook, you'll find more information about how to do that at the link below:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login